# Geographic location settings

Tags: google, google-search-console, search-results

I am building a website and it uses a Netherlands (`.nl`) domain. This domain is being found when using the Netherlands Google. I'd like the site to be found on all Google's not just country speific such as `.co.uk`, `.com` and so on.

I have looked on the Google forums and I've read that you can change the sites geographic position. I have done the nessarary changes to the site but in Google's Console (WMT) there is no select box as displayed by other users.

Screenshot of Google Webmaster Tools (nl)

[image: no selectbox in webmaster tools]

*Question(s):*

- What do  I need to do so that my site appears in Google's search results in other countries?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have a country specific TLD (eg. `.nl` - Netherlands) then you can't specify the geographic target in Google Webmaster Tools - it is already set to whatever region matches the TLD.

You can only specify the region yourself if you have a generic (non-country specific) TLD such as `.com` or `.org`.

However, this does not mean that your site won't appear on google.com or even google.co.uk, providing your content is deemed relevant to those users. Having a country specific TLD (or specifying a particular geographic target for a generic TLD) makes your site more relevant in a localised search but not necessarily any less relevant in a global search.

### An example...

If I search for (what I think is) your full name on google.com then there is already a link to (what I think is) your site at #7 on page 1 of the SERPs! (The same on google.co.uk as it happens)

However, if I do the same search on google.nl, and do not specify English as the search language then your site does not appear on the first 5 pages. (If I specify 'English' as the search language then your site pops up - your site is in English.)

So, you are already global! :)